# Alarm Manager Firing Immediately after real time has been passed

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I want to set and cancel an Alarm for a particular time. I am doing the same using the TimePicker using the following code.

```
public void setRecurringAlarm(int randomTimer,long mills, int i){
        Intent intent = new Intent(CreateAlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("timer:" + i));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(CreateAlarmActivity.this, 1253, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,mills,
                pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(CreateAlarmActivity.this, "Alarm "+i+" isSet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**Note:**-Suppose I set the alarm for 10:00 PM. It works fine for 10:00 PM. But when I again run the same code (after 10 PM) i.e once the time has been passed on which the alarm has been set and I recall that code (to reset the alarm), it starts running immediately. Why it is so ? I am unable to get where I am a wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the alarm time is before the current time or not. If so, then set the alert time for the next day (if you want to fire alarm at least once, or want to set Repeating alarm).

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
if (System.currentTimeMillis() > cal.getTimeInMillis()) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void scheduleAlarm() {
    // time at which alarm will be scheduled here alarm is scheduled at 1
    // day from current time,
    // we fetch the current time in milliseconds and added 1 day time
    // i.e. 24*60*60*1000= 86,400,000 milliseconds in a day
    // Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+24*60*60*1000;

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    Intent intent = new Intent(CreateAlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

    // create the object
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    // set the alarm for particular time
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Scheduled ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();



}
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1. If you are "recalling that code" by calling `setRecurringAlarm(randomTimer, mills, i)` using the same value for the `mills` parameter, then the time for the alarm will be in the past and it will trigger immediately (if you schedule an alarm with a trigger time in the past, the alarm triggers immediately).
2. Please remove `|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA` from the call to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`. It doesn't belong there as this parameter should contain only `PendingIntent` flags and it may do some damage.